# Not able to read the product ID from ADIS16260 Gyroscope Sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

I have interfaced a ADIS1620 sensor to the Arduino UNO using SPI.I am having a bit of trouble here to read the product ID information from the ADIS1620.According to the datasheet [here](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADIS16260_16265.pdf),

on page 11, it is said that to perform a read operation, 2 16bit transactions are to be done with a minimum stall time of 9 us. The first 16 bit consists of the register address to read from i.e. 0x5600 and the second transaction is to read the product ID information. However, I always get the read data as '0' or as '0xFFFF'.I have done the hardware interfacing as per the connections mentioned below:

```
/* SPI Connections as per pg No.10 in 
   the Datasheet (Note: Not using IRQ)
 */

 ADIS1620                 UNO
  (DIN)3                11 - MOSI
  (DOUT)2               12 - MISO
  (SCLK)1               13 - SCK
  (SS)4                 10 - CS
  16                    5V
  18                    GND
```

Below is .h file,

```
#ifndef ADIS16260_H
#define ADIS16260_H

/* Register Addresses */
#define LOT_ID1_ADDR          0x5200
#define LOT_ID2_ADDR          0x5400
#define PROD_ID_ADDR          0x5600
#define SERIAL_NUM_ADDR       0x5800

/* Timings */
#define STALL_TIME_US         10

#endif /* ADIS16260_H */
```

I doubt the problem is to do anything with the code as such, but still, just in case, here is the .ino file,

```
/* Lib's Include */
#include <SPI.h>

/* Custom Lib's Include */
#include "adis16260.h"

/* MACRO's */
#define CS  10

/* Globals */
char incomingByte;
unsigned int prod_info_data;

/* Definitions */
typedef enum
{
  LOT_ID1,
  LOT_ID2,
  PROD_ID,
  SERIAL_NUM
} Prod_InfoT;

/* Function Prototypes */
void SPI_Init();
unsigned int Get_Product_Info(Prod_InfoT get_adis16260_info);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI_Init();
  Serial.println("SPI Initialized");

}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    if (incomingByte == 'a')
    {
      prod_info_data = Get_Product_Info(PROD_ID);
      Serial.println(prod_info_data, HEX);
    }
  }
}

/********************************************************************************
   Function Name    : SPI_Init
   Description      : Initialize the SPI module in the MCU
   Returns          : None
 * *****************************************************************************/
void SPI_Init()
{
  /* configure the line as output */
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);

  /* Initialize the CS line to HIGH */
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);

  /* Initialize the SPI module--> configures the MOSI, MISO and CLOCK lines */
  SPI.begin();

  /*
    Configure the SPI bus as follows
      1. SPI bus speed  = 1 MHz
      2. Data Out     = From MSB bit ---> To LSB bit
      3. Data Mode    = SPI MODE3
  */
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(100000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
}

/********************************************************************************
   Function Name    : Get_Product_Info
   Description      : Get Prod ID, Lot ID1, Lot ID2 and Serial Num.
   Returns          : None
 * *****************************************************************************/
unsigned int Get_Product_Info(Prod_InfoT get_adis16260_info)
{
  unsigned int get_data = 0;

  switch (get_adis16260_info)
  {
    case PROD_ID:
      Serial.println("Reading Product ID...");
      digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
      SPI.transfer16(PROD_ID_ADDR);
      digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(STALL_TIME_US);
      digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
      get_data = SPI.transfer16(0x00);
      digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
      break;

    case SERIAL_NUM:
      Serial.println("Reading Serial Number...");
      digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
      SPI.transfer16(SERIAL_NUM_ADDR);
      digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(STALL_TIME_US);
      digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
      get_data = SPI.transfer16(0x00);
      digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
      break;

    default:
      Serial.println("Invalid Arguement");
      break;
  }
  return (get_data);
}
```

Edit: Added screen shot of the SPI lines:
[image] 
Any support with this would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Does you code return the serial number?

Comment: @Code Gorilla, I have tried reading the serial number as well, the same issue happens i.e. Reads 0 or 0xFFFF.

Comment: Good, that means its not a fault with the device.  Should the first param of SPISettings be 1 million or 100,000?   I've never used SPI, but doesn't the SPI object handle the CS pin?

Comment: @CodeGorilla, the SPI bus speed is set to 100 KHz i.e. 100000. No, the chip select line needs to be handled manually.

Comment: Reading all 0xFFFF suggests the gryo is not driving MISO, either as it is not operational or has not received a valid read command or been selected.  You need to show the wiring of your gyro chip.  Who soldered the QFN?  QFN's are notorious for having metalizations look connected when they actually are not.  For your software, do you have another SPI peripheral you can run a quick test against?  Investing in a scope or even a cheap USB fifo based logic analyzer will be very useful for investigating this type of problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, while reading,  most of the time I receive '0' and sometimes in between I receive '0xFFFF'(So it means that the gyro is responding with a 0x00? and sometimes 0xFFFF due to some connection issues??), need to check this. The QFN was soldered by a hardware engineer. I have a USB logic analyzer, I will prob the signals and check if the SPI lines are working fine.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get that hardware engineer involved.  Both bus traffic analysis, and inspecting the QFN fillets under high magnification from an angle would be appropriate (I usually raise the microscope so I can hold the board in my hand and tilt it to the best angle)

Comment: @ChrisStratton, unfortunately the hardware engineer had left 2 months ago. Between, I guess the SPI signals look good, what do you think? (have attached the image). Before concluding for a hardware check to my boss, I want to make sure that there's nothing wrong being done on the firmware side. And, do I need to do a full fledge timing analysis w.r.t the timing requirements that needs to be met for the ADIS16260?

Comment: Try putting a pullup resistor on MISO so you can see if it is undriven or stuck.  Check the data sheet for the gyro - many chips will clock out some sort of status word even from the first byte of SPI access.  If you can find *any* other SPI peripheral, it may be worth experimenting with that and trying to adapt your software to it, as in so doing you may realize some oversight.  Finally there are other gyros out there pre-soldered on modules with Arduino libraries already in existence - if you get really stuck maybe you can use one of those, at least until you get a hardware engineer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, just to get it right, you mean to say that I need to test the Arduino UNO's SPI interface with another device that uses SPI interface? or a different MCU itself  SPI to communicate with the Gyro?

Comment: I was proposing you use another SPI peripheral to gain some hands-on experience and validate (an adapted version of) your SPI code.  But trying another MCU with the gyro could be an option too, if you have something that is a substantially different implementation.